# variable not being passed on when making a call through cfajaxproxy to a cffunction

Tags: coldfusion

```
function getStateInfo(state){
  alert(state);
  var f = new funcs();
  f.setCallbackHandler(updateFormFieldStateInfo);
  f.setQueryFormat('column');
  f.qry_getLenderEvictionStateInfo(<cfoutput>#request.Lender_Id#</cfoutput>,state);
}
```

doesn't pass the state value to the ColdFusion function

Comment: That's a really poor problem description. Please be more precise.

Comment: I'll have to agree with Tomalak, you aren't providing nearly enough information here to help you. What does your CFC look like? is qry_getLenderEvictionStateInfo() supposed to be a method of an object? The funcs object? (I'm guessing that's your CFC). Help us help you.

Answer (score 0):

Here are a few observations that may help:

Is the alert() function defined in your prior code or is it being confused with javascript's alert() function? I don't believe that [Coldfusion has](http://livedocs.adobe.com/coldfusion/8/htmldocs/help.html?content=functions-pt0_01.html) a built in alert() function unless it's new in version 9.

A caution, not a problem, the var keyword must be defined at the very top of the function body unless you are using Coldfusion 9. Likewise, the "new" keyword is new to CF 9. I'm guessing you're on version 9 since you're using both features.

For pre-Coldfusion 9:

```
function getStateInfo(state){
    var f = createobject("component","functs");
    alert(state);
    ...
```

Don't put the  tags within cfscript. You don't need the hash marks either, although they won't cause harm. Hash marks are intended for use outside of coldfusion tags (including cfscript), in the main body of the html.

This line:

```
 f.qry_getLenderEvictionStateInfo(<cfoutput>#request.Lender_Id#</cfoutput>,state);
```

Should be:

```
 f.qry_getLenderEvictionStateInfo(request.Lender_Id,state);
```